# A REST API needs to call a URL, but has problems accessing the script deployed as a web app

Tags: google-apps-script, twilio

I am making a REST call to a service which then requires a connection to a stable URL. I published my script as a web app and then tried to use that URL, Twilio's (the REST api I am working with) response said that it doesn't have access to the Google Apps Script stable URL. For more specific information on what the call back URL necessitates.
http://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/making-calls#url-parameter
Thanks!

Comment: Have you published it as a web app and allowed access to anyone, including anonymous users ?

Comment: Were you able to make this work? I have used GAS to access Twilio. I may be able to help.

Answer (score 0):

Rob from Twilio here.  You may want to check out the GAS team's screencast on [how to use Twilio with GAS](https://developers.google.com/live/shows/11404657).  They highlight during the deployment process you must make sure that you set the permission for "Who has access to the app" is set to "Everyone".  Can you give that a try and see if that makes it work for you?